# Given $\mathrm{Nul} A,$ a solution $\vec x$ for $A\vec x = \vec b,$ and $\mathrm{proj}_{\mathrm{Col}A}\vec b,$ how would I find $\vec b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A$ is a $4 \times 6$ matrix, $$\mathcal{B} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix} ,  \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
-2 
\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$ is a basis for $\operatorname{Nul} A,$ $\vec b\in\operatorname{Col}A,$ $$\vec x = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
2 
\end{pmatrix} $$ is a
particular solution to $\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{Col}A}\vec b =  \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
-1 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}.$

Give the sum of the components in $\vec b.$

It seems like there's not enough information to solve for $\vec b$ but I must be missing some relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is camouflaged  with overspecification; it provides information that isn't needed. To solve the problem, just sort out the fundamental subspaces.

---

**Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra**

Start here with the fundamental subspaces induced by a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$:

$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$
Use the problem statements to clarify this picture.

---

In the general linear system
$$
 \mathbf{A} x = b, 
$$
the data vector has $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{null}$ spaces:
$$
 b = 
\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} +
\color{red} {b_{\mathcal{N}}}
\tag{1}
$$
and the solution vector will has different $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{null}$ spaces for the particular and homogenous components:
$$
  x = 
\color{blue}{x_{part}} + \color{red}{x_{homo}}
\tag{2}
$$

---

Parse the problem statement. We are given
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} x &= b \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \star & \star & \star & \star & \star & \star \\
 \star & \star & \star & \star & \star & \star \\
 \star & \star & \star & \star & \star & \star \\
 \star & \star & \star & \star & \star & \star \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\
 2 \\
-1 \\
 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

The target matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{4\times 6}_{4}$. The rank $\rho=4$ is inferred because the column space has dimension $6$ and $2$ vectors span the $\color{red}{null}$ space $(6-2=4)$. (We know the two vectors are linearly independent because they are stated as forming a basis.)

Therefore, the matrix has *full row rank*: $m=\rho=4$.

Therefore, we have a trivial $\color{red}{null}$ space:
$$
\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)} = \mathbf{0}
$$

Therefore the data vector does *not* have a $\color{red}{null}$ space component.

Therefore (1) reduces
$$
 b = 
\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}}
$$
Because $\color{red}{b_{\mathcal{N}}}=0$, we have complete information about $b$.

Therefore, the sum of the elements in the data vector is
$$
\boxed{
\sum_{r=1}^{4} b_{r} = 1 + 2 -1 + 1 = 3
}
$$

Comment: Here's [something to consider](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4195/28900).

Comment: @Cameron Buie: Thanks for the link. Do you think colors should not be used, or that they are used to detriment in this case? (Note, I suffer from minor color blindness, so my color choices sometimes conflict with good taste.) Comments from others also welcome.

Comment: I'd say that, when there are only a few distinctions that need to be made, it can be done in ways that don't involve color differences. When there are enough differences, colors almost have to be used.